# LAMPP mysql can't create err file and doesn't have uninstall file

Tags: uninstall, lamp, xampp

I am very, very new to Ubuntu and I just started using it.

I installed Xampp server on it by downloading Xampp from their website and installing it with Ubuntu Software.

But when I try to find it in Ubuntu Software installation list, it does not exist.

My first problem was by starting xampp:

```
cd ../../opt/lampp/
sudo ./lampp start
```

And I get this:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux ...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
myName@MyName:/opt$ /opt/lampp/bin/mysqld_safe_helper: Can't create/write to file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/MyName.err' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
```

I was looking online for answer but for that I didn't found anything that worked...

So I guess I should install everything by itself without xampp and now when I want to uninstall for some reason I can't and probably I do not know how because it is not installed by `apt-get` so I cannot uninstall with `apt-get remove`.

And I searched for this also and everyone keeps talking about doing this:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/uninstall
```

But I do not have any uninstall files in entire lampp folder...

This is the version that I downloaded and installed:

```
xampp-linux-x64-5.6.30-0-installer.run
```

Comment: **1)** What is the output of `ls -l /opt/lampp/var/mysql`? **2)** Like error message suggests, try adding Write permission to the folder and file. Use `chmod ug+w /opt/lampp/var/mysql && chmod ug+w /opt/lampp/var/mysql/MyName.err`.

Comment: You can't remove it using `apt-get` as you didn't install via that root. Now search for this uninstall file with" `ls -al /opt/lampp | grep uninstal`. You should have an uninstall fill in there

Comment: @SamuelSantana : chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/lampp/var/mysql': Operation not permitted

Comment: @Sky You don't own the dir/file, so you'll need to add `sudo`, sorry.

Comment: @SamuelSantana : chmod: cannot access '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/MyName.err': No such file or directory

Comment: Ah!, the file doesn't exist, XAMPP never got to create it. Doesn't matter, now try running xampp again.

Comment: @SamuelSantana same as on start: myName@MyName:/opt$ /opt/lampp/bin/mysqld_safe_helper: Can't create/write to file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/MyName.err' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")

Comment: I created a chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/55256/askubuntu-com-questions-892461?tab=general

Comment: I need 20 rep to talk?

Comment: Oh dang... well, you can edit your answer and post the things that I asked you in the chat.

Comment: I may reinstall ubuntu, for some reasons it is crashing from nowhere no lags no nothing just everything freezes, i installed it  5h ago and it crashed 6 times till now

Answer (score 4):

I think you change the owner of /opt/lampp. So you need to give owner to `/opt/lampp/var/mysql`. Use the following code:

`sudo chown mysql:mysql -R /opt/lampp/var/mysql`

I have same problem too and solved it.

Comment: I'm starting couldn't run mysql server right after I do change all ownership inside lampp folder to my username with `sudo chown myusername:myusername -R /opt/lampp/*`. Using above command, finally I could run mysql server again.

Comment: I'm getting error as `chown: invalid user: ‘mysql:mysql’ `

Comment: @SudhakarKrishnan I think you haven't mysql user, Its possible you removed it. change it to your username. Please remember to use `sudo` at the first of command.  If this doesn't work, please check next comment.

Comment: @SudhakarKrishnan Use `sudo adduser mysql` to create mysql user. Now use the this code `sudo chown mysql:mysql -R /opt/lampp/var/mysql` to change mysql dir user. Then give the correct permissions `sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/var/mysql`. At the end of this, start your mysql.

Comment: @Hamidreza Thankyou, it worked for me.